# Adobe Export Release Build doesn't work - Mac OSX - Flex Builder 3

Tags: apache-flex, air, flexbuilder

I have an AIR application i'm trying to release with flexbuilder.

Launching application has no problem ... bin-debug dir is correctly filled with my files.

But when i want to create the AIR file (export release fuild), AIR files content view is empty and bin-debug directory is never filled ...

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Yannick Grenzinger

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Seemed to be a problem with the XML config file for the application. Create a new MXML application, (something named different clearly). Copy and paste the code from the other app over. Bam, it works again!  Hope this helps your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue recently with the Export Release Build. I added the icon paths in the air app xml as below -

```
<icon>
   <image16x16>assets/icons/logo_16.png</image16x16>
   <image32x32>assets/icons/logo_32.png</image32x32>
   <image36x36></image36x36>
   <image48x48></image48x48>
   <image72x72></image72x72>
   <image128x128></image128x128>
</icon>
```

This caused the issue. Commented the above lines and it worked without any issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you export a release build; you are given the option to specify a directory.  I believe this is named "bin-release" by default, a least for Flex projects.  Are you sure you specified this correct directory?

The output of an AIR project export will be a .AIR ile which you need to install on your machine to run.  Have you done that?

If your project has multiple application files, make sure you are exporting the proper one.

I'm unclear what you mean when you refer to the "AIR Files Content View."

Comment: "When you export a release build; you are given the option to specify a directory. Are you sure you specified this correct directory?"
No just the name and location of the AIR "export build" file.

"The output of an AIR project export." 
Ok and I have to do packaging to have the installing .dmg file. But my problem is i  can't create this air file.

"AIR Files Content View." It is one of the view steps when you do "export release build". Normally it contains the list of files contained by the AIR (or AIRI) file. In my case, it's empty.

Comment: ISn't a DMG file a Mac installer?  Are you using AIR 2.0 ?  Or do you plan to wrap up the AIR application as part of your own installer?  
I just exported my a test release build and did not have the "AIR Files Content View" as part of the export.  Are you sure you have the correct project / application selected?

Comment: Oops, I spoke to soon; the AIR Files Content View showed up after clicking Finish.  I'm not sure why files wouldn't be listed in it; mine lists the main application file and the XML config file.

Comment: Yes normally .. but not in my case :)
Really interested to know where it can come from !

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just got the same issue!

Here's what I found out (even though I have not found a great solution for this yet). While exporting the release build, Flex Builder generates a directory named "bin_release" where all files to be included in the package are dumped. To fix my issue, so far all I have to do is to copy all the missing files into this directory before I click "finish" in the Export Release wizard.

Not a final solution but its a quick work around!